# Extract the value of a variable that matches a pattern in TCL

Tags: tcl

I have a list called parameters and the content of this list can be different but it will look something like:

```
var1=2;
var2=2'h2;
var3=2'h0;
....
```

This list comes from reading a file and done some preformating already. I just want to grab the value of var1 and store it in a variable. Eg whatever is in between '=' sign and ';' sign but only for var1 (in this case number 2). Equally I can remove all the lines that are not matching 'var1'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `parameters` list is already set, you can do something like:

```
foreach item $parameters {
  if {[regexp "var1\\s*=\\s*(\\w+);" $item wholeMatch myVal]} {
       break
  }
}
puts "value is '$myVal'"
```

The regular expression I use allows for optional spaces before and after the equal sign. Take a look at [Tcl's regex syntax](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm) and adjust as necessary.

It might be easier to just do a regex search through your whole file using, rather than parsing your file into a list. But again, take a look at Tcl's documentation.

Comment: Don't use `\w` -- that won't match the single quote: use `([^;]*)`

Comment: Good catch! Thanks.